# 2012 11" MacBook Air automatically turns on when power cable attached

Tags: power-management, macbook-air

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a 2012 11" MacBook Air and enabled disk encryption.

When I turn off the machine, I wait for the disk to encrypt and the machine to power off.  Then I close the lid.

In that situation, if I attach the power cable the machine automatically powers up (i.e., turns on), even with the lid closed.

The machine never did this during the many versions of OS X it had, nor does my wife's identical machine (which still runs an OS X) do it.

Is there a way to disable this activity?